# Move-ADObject to same OU as another user

Tags: powershell

Im creating new user from clone user so far have everything in place except I cant get the new user to be moved to the same OU as my clone user, we have over 250 OU's so editing Script for move-ADObject each time is not Ideal as some staff new to powershell I can get the Clone user OU as Vairable but when running Script keep getting access denied Im on test lab and the domain administrator/Owner so should have all permissions have chhecked the opjects in ADUC and both are unticket for accidental deletion.

```
$user = Get-ADUser -Identity "User1"
$User2 = "OUTEST"

$userOU = ($user.DistinguishedName -split "=",3)[-1]

Write-Host $userOU # only to view output 

$oupath = Get-aduser $User2
$x = $user.DistinguishedName

Move-ADObject -Identity $x -TargetPath $userOU #Move new user to Accounts OU
```

Output and error:-

```
Move-ADObject : Access is denied
At line:11 char:1
+ Move-ADObject -Identity $x -TargetPath $userOU
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (CN=test1 user,O...an,DC=gov,DC=uk:ADObject) [Move-ADObject], UnauthorizedAccessException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryCmdlet:System.UnauthorizedAccessException,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.MoveADObject
```

Comment: You're trying to move the user to its own OU..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As commented, your code tries to move a user ($user) to the same OU it is already in. It never uses `$User2` ..

Try

```
# get the OU from the first user (the OU to move the other user into)
$OU    = ((Get-ADUser -Identity 'User1').DistinguishedName -split '(?<!\\),', 2)[-1]
# next, get the user object of the user you want to move
$User2 = Get-ADUser -Identity 'User2'

# now move user2 to the OU where user1 is in
$User2 | Move-ADObject -TargetPath $OU
```

You may have to add parameter `-Credential` to the `Move-ADObject` call where you can give it credentials of an admin user that is allowed to move user objects.
The easiest way to get such a credential object is by using

```
$cred = Get-Credential -Message 'Please enter credentials'
```

Regex details for the split:

```
(?<!        Assert that it is impossible to match the regex below with the match ending at this position (negative lookbehind)
   \\       Match the character “\” literally
)          
,           Match the character “,” literally
```